# How to parse socket emit data from script

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to make a modification for the game moomoo.io using a tampermonkey/greasemonkey script.

I want to be able to change the data emitted from the client. Particularly, if the first argument is "2", I do not want the data to be sent.
The code I have now will cause all data to stop being emitted  for some reason.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Here is my code:

```
var injection = [];
injection.push("var _emit = socket.emit;");
injection.push("socket.emit = function(ev) {");
injection.push("    if (arguments[0] !== '2') {");
injection.push("        return _emit(ev)");
injection.push("    } else {");
injection.push("        console.log('do nothing')");
injection.push("    }");
injection.push("};");
scri = document.createElement("script");
scri.innerHTML = injection.join("\n");
$("body").append(scri);
injection.length = 0;
used = true;
```